# Unit test for function in different directory is giving error

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I'm trying to write a unit test for the GCD code written [here](https://github.com/rajcspsg/ProgrammingRust/blob/master/src/chapter1/gcd.rs). I'm also trying to write unit tests for this function. The test is [here](https://github.com/rajcspsg/ProgrammingRust/blob/master/tests/gcd.rs)

This is the directory structure of the project:

```
ProgrammingRust $ tree
.
├── Cargo.lock
├── Cargo.toml
├── README.md
├── src
│   ├── chapter1
│   │   ├── cmd_line_args.rs
│   │   └── gcd.rs
│   └── main.rs
├── target
│   ├── debug
│   │   ├── 
└── tests
    ├── chapter1
    └── gcd.rs

48 directories, 108 files
```

When I try to run the tests, I get this error:

```
error[E0432]: unresolved import `chapter1`
--> tests/gcd.rs:1:7
1 |   use chapter1;
  |       ^^^^^^^^ no `chapter1` in the root

error[E0425]: cannot find function `gcd` in this scope
--> tests/gcd.rs:10:20
   |
10 |         assert_eq!(gcd(15, 14), 1);
   |                    ^^^ not found in this scope
```

I want to access the function in `src/chapter1/gcd.rs` at `tests/gcd.rs`, but I don't know how to link the function `gcd.rs` to a test in the `tests` folder.

Comment: Please include the relevant code (ideally a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)) in the question.

Answer (score 0):

In Rust, tests that exist under a `tests` directory are what's known as "black box" tests and treat the tested crate as if it were an `extern` library. What you want is

```
extern crate chapter1;

// ...
```

If you want to do white box tests (and have access to the private members), create a module that only compiles under `#[cfg(test)]` like so:

```
#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    #[test]
    fn test_foo() {
        // may use any `use` declaration as if this were any
        // other module
        use super::Something;
    }
 }
```

You can also create a file just like a normal module, and only wrap the corresponding `mod` declaration like so: `#[cfg(test)] mod tests;`